# Android MonkeyImage to binary

Tags: android, ruby, sockets, android-emulator, monkeyrunner

I'm implementing to take Emulator's screen capture by using Android MonkeyImage.
The captured data is sent to Ruby script through TCPSocket and try to save it as jpg image.
But I don't know how to convert the sent String data to Binary with Ruby.
The code is as follows.

```
[client.py]

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyImage
import socket
import sys
import base64

server_address = ('localhost', 9898)
print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(server_address)

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(60 , "emulator-5554")

while True:

    sc   = device.takeSnapshot().convertToBytes("jpg")
    size = str(len(sc)).zfill(16)

    sock.sendall(size)
    sock.sendall(sc)

    print >>sys.stderr, 'sended'

sock.close()

[server.rb]

#!/usr/bin/ruby                                                                 
# coding: utf-8                                                                 
require "socket"

s0 = TCPServer.open(9898)
sock = s0.accept
count = 0
loop do

  size  = sock.recv(16).to_i
  image = sock.recv(size)

  File.open("/Users/taicsuzu/Downloads/ss4/test"+count.to_s+".jpg", "wb") do |file|                                                  
    #file.write(image.unpack("B*"))[0]
    #file.write(image)                                          
    #file.write(image.encode("BINARY"))                                                          
  end

  p image
  count += 1

end
sock.close
s0.close
```

The results are as follows.

```
"\xFF\xD8\xFF\xDB\x00C\x00\ ...
```

How can I convert the ascii string data to Image Binary?
The commented out line (file.write()...) is not working that generates invalid image or black image.
Thanks for all helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to obtain the screenshot either via `dump` command line utility or a python script which you can generate using `culebra`.

First, command line

```
$ dump -Df ~/tmp/sc1.png
```

`dump` does not have an option to save screenshot as JPEG as they are usually saved as PNG (but could be a nice addition).

On the other hand, via a python script autogenerated by `culebra` and where I manually edited the PNG by JPEG

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2016  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2016-09-03 by Culebra v11.5.11
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

_s = 5
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)
#vc.dump(window='-1') # FIXME: seems not needed

vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.writeImageToFile('/tmp/${serialno}-${focusedwindowname}-${timestamp}.jpg', 'JPEG', None, False, False)
```

Notice that filenames are autogenerated so if you run the script multiple times they are not overwritten.

Depending on what you are intending to use the screenshots for, device art, shadows and glare can be automatically added, see http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-beautiful-screenshots-take-2.html

## EDIT

Good news, AndroidViewClient/culebra 11.5.12 supports

```
$ dump -Df ~/tmp/sc1.jpg
```